# Closing node.js http server in setTimeout difference

Tags: node.js, http

The following node.js program doesn't exit:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337,'127.0.0.1');

server.close();
```

But this one does:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337,'127.0.0.1');

function closeServer() {
  server.close();
};

setTimeout(closeServer,1);
```

No connections are made to the server. Can someone explain the reason for the change in behaviour between the programs? I've just tried this on Windows 7 with node.js version 0.12.5.

Comment: Interesting... I believe it will behave same if you replace delay 1 with 0?

Comment: I tried your first example, it throws error and closes. You don't get the error?

Comment: It errors on version 0.10 but listens on version 0.12

Comment: @hassansin I don't get the throw/error in the first example. It just listens and handles requests indefinitely. Replacing the delay of 1 with 0 makes no difference: i.e. it still exits the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Node.JS HTTP documentation of [`server.listen`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback):

> .. This function is asynchronous. ..

so if you see the code below by the time when you call `server.close()` because `server.listen` is being executed asynchronously you are closing a server that didn't start yet.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello world\n');
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  console.log('server up and running');
});

server.close();

server.on('close', function() {
  console.log('closed server');
});
```

Here is the proof, after you close the server, then the server is ready:

```
closed server
server up and running
```

---

But if you call the `server.close` method inside the callback of the `server.listen` (that means that the server is ready), you will be able to shut down the server.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello world\n');
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  console.log('server up and running');
  server.close();
});

server.on('close', function() {
  console.log('closed server');
});
```

output:

```
server up and running
closed server
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for advancing my understanding of node.js.